# C# Написать рекурсивную функцию для нахождения максимального числа в введённой пользователем строке

Tags: c#, функции, рекурсия

**Срочно нужна помощь!**

> Решить поставленную задачу с использованием рекурсивной и обычной функций. 
>   Сравнить полученные результаты между собой.
>
> Задача:
>   найти максимальный элемент в массиве a[i] (i=1,..., n), 
>   используя соотношение (деления пополам) max(a[1],..., a[n]) = max[max(a[1],..., a[n/2]), max(a[n/2+1], ..., a[n])].

Обычная функция для сравнения уже имеется, пытался из всякого и палок склеить рекурсию, весь результат моих "дум" снизу, но полоса неудач в виде нескольких дней сидения перед монитором из-за постоянных ошибок опустила мои руки в надежде самостоятельно найти решение проблемы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Recursion
{
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите массив через запятые.");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        text = text.Trim(new char[] { ',', '.' }); //удаление точек и запятых
        string[] textArray = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }); //разбиваем текст на слова (в массив строк)

        Console.WriteLine("words num: " + textArray.Length);
        if (textArray.Length == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Не с чем сравнивать.");

        if (Standart(textArray, textArray.Length) == Pain(textArray, textArray.Length))
        Console.WriteLine("Результаты равны");

        else
        Console.WriteLine("Результаты не равны");



    }

    public static int Standart(string[] ar, int col)
    {
        int max = int.Parse(ar[0]), maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            if (max < int.Parse(ar[i]))
            {
                max = int.Parse(ar[i]);
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    public static int Pain(string[] ar, int col)
    {

        Console.Write("Массив: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(ar[i]);
            Console.Write(' ');
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n Максимальное: ");
            Console.Write(findMax(ar[i], col));
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static int findMax(string mas, int col)
    {
        int mas1 = int.Parse(mas);  
        int halfcol = col / 2;
            int oneh = findMax(mas, halfcol);
            int twoh = findMax(mas + halfcol, col - halfcol);

            if (oneh > twoh)
                return oneh;
            else
                return twoh;

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку в C# кажется нет простого и понятного способа отрезать часть массива, а передавать в функцию вам надо именно массив, а не отдельный элемент, как вы это делаете, наверное проще всего сделать так, передавая кроме самого массива начальный и конечный индексы той его части, в которой нужно искать максимум:

```
static int findMax(string mas, int index1, int index2)
{
    if(index1 == index2)
        return int.Parse(mas[index1]);

    int halfcol = (index1 + index2) / 2;
    int oneh = findMax(mas, index1, halfcol);
    int twoh = findMax(mas, halfcol + 1, index2);
    if (oneh > twoh)
        return oneh;
    else
        return twoh;
} 

Console.Write(findMax(ar, 0, col - 1));
```

Код не проверял, но идея, надеюсь, понятна.